# How to create a type that yields a dot notation of nested class properties as string literals?

Tags: typescript

This is related to the AWS SDK, which has several clients, wherein each one there are namespaces with properties.

This library exports `AWS`, which has several clients, e.g. `DynamoDB`and `ACM`. `DynamoDB` has a property called `DocumentClient`. `ACM` has a property called `CertificateBody`.

```js
class _DocumentClient {}
namespace _DocumentClient {}

// DynamoDB that is imported in the AWS module (see below)
declare class _DynamoDB {}
declare namespace _DynamoDB {
  export import DocumentClient = _DocumentClient;
}

// ACM client that is imported in the AWS module (see below)
declare class _ACM {}
declare namespace _ACM {
  export type CertificateBody = string;
}

// AWS module (mimicking)
// The original library (as linked above) exports a lot more clients...
namespace AWS {
  export import ACM = _ACM;
  export import DynamoDB = _DynamoDB;
}
```

I'm trying to create a type that yields a union of string literals like `"DynamoDB.DocumentClient" | "ACM.CertificateBody"`.

I've tried getting the list of all of the properties of each client, but that seems to be an impossible task, let alone appending a client and property with a dot notation.

I only managed to get the `prototype` string literal instead of the wanted `DocumentClient` and `CertificateBody` string literals.

```js
// this works - ("ADM" | "DynamoDB")
type ClientName = keyof typeof AWS; 

// shouldn't this yield "DocumentClient" | "CertificateBody"? Using this type only means I can use "prototype" :/
type NestedClientName<C extends ClientName> = keyof typeof AWS[C]; 

// I want to be able to get a type with a union of string literals like `"ACM.CertificateBody" | "DynamoDB.DocumentClient" 
type NestedClientFullName<C extends ClientName, NC extends NestedClientName<C>> = `${C}.${NC}`;
```

Unfortunately, neither `NestedClientName` (and by consequence, `NestedClientFullName`) are yielding fair results.

[Here is a permalink to the full file on GitHub for context](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/clients/all.d.ts), to show the original `aws-sdk` file. I've reproduced it on both snippets above and on the playground below.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBEE8DsEMFsD24BCBYAUAYwDawM76gD64iWArvAKbQAuAwjgJa12gDeAvpnDfgAdYWaiTKUa9Jq3qceGTABNquWACdRqwmJgJkKOUpV4NoPtUHDRpXUlSdMoUNQAeAxGvbN47zxHJUbNJsoAC8YgGSjCxsANyY8pggoACCDACyRqqmWkTEaemGGMrZouaWIiQFDhhOrr7sdJACogzUnswAZsxYsHTUKIiKkGGg+HRqzNAA5vEYiRjJKQDqAMq8CBZClSurNXVuHl4+R6kZo-kZcwcNoN63UHz6F496qNegS2ugABYEoLBQHRENBQIhOmC6D92qBcDI6PgAHTIhKYNEKRZgdIjSjjRDwIHNCxAv7sACSoAA7rBZMDQNNqOx8EdqIpQAA3Tlc7k83no+qnJotUDBegAOU2owA1tRIODCS15btYp8wFDmERKR4pfh+Yc-ELRGKLP1FKK6BKaAAeBjOFz9aCKIjmy3UAB80tl8sNSrWAG0GABdFXJfA-RAUHCKaAAckaPw1oEgrCjoAAROJAlIYvQ06AAD7ptodbq9fqDYZpgD86KSYAp1NpiFAACNRLAWzhRHSGexAYaqcwoQDQBRoMwQWCIeNJjNQCx+mpYDgiCwZaAAAZpgqI4t0Lo9PoDIaQPOFjO2fSIzNRc1pzACg1E0DG8as80AMUjOFdNrtDqdEUcwtTYABoX1tVwAKIV9TRdTYbTdD1wg3AASDgGC4RF0LFTCNxVWsMSAA)

Comment: ① Please [edit] this question to include the relevant code here directly as plaintext.  An external link to an IDE or to github is a nice *supplement* but does not suffice to be a [mre].  Right now the question risks being closed as needing debugging details. ② Why would you expect to see `"DocumentClient"`? That's just a type, it does not exist as a property key of anything.  I can imagine getting `"CertificateClient"`, but nothing has a property named `DocumentClient` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jcalz. I've edited the question, should be clearer now.
In the context of `aws-sdk` (which is what I tried to reproduce), they have lots of clients (e.g. `DynamoDB`), each one with namespaces that export properties (e.g `DocumentClient`). I've added two examples to the Typescript playground.

I'm trying to create a type that allows me to create a dot-notation of the `{client}.{property}` string literal across all clients of `aws-sdk`. So, in this small example, it'd be `DynamoDB.DocumentClient`, amongst. others.

Hopefully I've made the problem clearer :)

Comment: Hmm, let me try again (maybe I got the names switched around).  In `AWS.ACM`, your `CertificateBody` is just a *type*, so it does not exist as a key of `AWS.ACM`.  You can access the type like `AWS.ACM.CertificateBody`, but that exists in a separate namespace; (`AWS.ACM` and `typeof AWS.ACM` are not the same thing) you'd have to export a *value* for it to exist on `typeof AWS.ACM`, like [this](//tsplay.dev/wOrVdW).  What you're asking for is a non-starter if you expect to see type-only names as string literals. If you can change the type to a value we can proceed. If not, this is impossible.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz for the clarification. In that case, it seems it is impossible. If you check [`ACM`'s file](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/438045c3806ddb7f6778c1d6d07b90dc7863794c/clients/acm.d.ts#L140-L152), you'll see that it is a type, not a value. I was hoping I could somehow get these types names as string literals. As you've said, it's a non-starter because it's impossible :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code example, `ACM` does not actually have a property called `CertificateBody`, so what you are asking for is impossible, at least for the parts of your task involving exported types.

---

In TypeScript, [`namespace`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) can act both as *values* that exist at runtime and hold properties, and as *namespaces for types* that exist only in TypeScript code.  When you `export` a value (like a `const` or a `function`) from a namespace it becomes a property on the namespace value.  When you export a type (like an `interface` or `type`) from a namespace it does not.

If you have a namespace named `Foo`, then `typeof Foo` will give you the type of the *value* named `Foo`, which contains any exported values as property keys.  It will not give you any access to the *type namespace* named `Foo`, or any way to list out the types that exist there.  Indeed there is no way to enumerate types in TypeScript:

```
declare namespace Foo {
    export const v: number;
    export type T = number;
}
type K = keyof typeof Foo;
// type K = "v"
```

Just to hammer home the idea that the type and the value are different: if you *only* export types and not values from a namespace, then there won't even be a value corresponding to the namespace:

```
declare namespace Bar {
    export const v: number;
}
const okay = Bar; // okay

declare namespace Baz {
    export type T = number;
}
const oops = Baz; // error
```

In the above, `typeof Bar` exists as an object type with a `number`-valued `v` property, but `typeof Baz` isn't a thing at all.  There *is* no value named `Baz` whose `type` you can get.  `Baz` is *only* a namespace for types.

---

So, `ACM` has no property named `CertificateBody`.  Instead the namespace `ACM` has a *type* called `CertificateBody`.  The type can be referenced directly in TypeScript as `ACM.CertificateBody`, but there is no way to access it programmatically, and definitely not as a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"CertificateBody"`.  Unfortunately what you are trying to do is impossible.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMCBiA9gfAN4CwAUPNfCAB6YEwAu8YBi6rAbgFxIBXFACMQMANyUatBk1bMAnpgQAVeAF5BIsZIoBfSouXwA0hvgBrEAoIAzeEZB34hAroD07h0oRnNAIm5-SkpQSFgEZDQsHAQAIVhSKRp6RhY2Di54Pi1RCUoDCnZOVgILKAVzBIl4T3gyipCKMOg4JFQMbFx4BIAvJKoU2XTHeDVNRCE83ULirKJMdCqoXvFarzEYJkogA)